# Multiplying the difference between today and a DateField by a number using Django Models

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I'm trying to get the difference in days between

1. the date each row of my table
2. The current date
   So I can then multiply it by a number. However I keep getting errors and exceptions. I searched Google, the Django docs, but couldn't find how. I even asked ChatGPT and Codeium but they keep giving completely wrong advice and direction.

If I over-simplify my model and query, There is the `History` table with all the rows containing the symbols, their type and their rank on a specific date.

```
class History(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=["type1", "type2", "type3"])
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    rank = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
```

Then with this query, I'm trying to get all the rows of "type1", then getting the difference in days between today and their `date` to multiply this amount by their rank:

```
compiled_type = (
    History.objects
    .values("symbol", "type")
    .filter(type="type1")
    .annotate(days_difference_delta=datetime.now().date() - F('date')) # This works and returns a TimeDelta
    .annotate(score=ExpressionWrapper((datetime.now().date() - F('date')) * F('rank')), output_field=IntegerField) # Getting a ton of errors and exceptions whatever I put on this line
    .order_by("-score").all()
)
```

Again it's over-simplifying as this is just the first step of a more complex calculation where I would group all rows by their `symbol` and Sum()`all the scores, but I'm trying to make this simple query work first. I tried without the`ExpressionWrapper`, I tried setting the` output_field`to`DecimalField`,` DateField`,` DurationField`, etc etc. But I have no idea what I'm doing and it seems like the Django docs is not really explaining much how this works.

So how can I multiply a `TimeDelta` to a number? Or how can I multiply a number by the days between 2 dates?